# weblogic deployment in production

Tags: weblogic11g

Hi
We are planning to have clustered setup for WebLogic domains and our application size is medium.Can anyone please advice which deployment mode is suitable for production.Will it be stage/nostage/external stage.Please let me know if possible why a particular mode is suitable

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare your scenario against [the three options listed on the Oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/deploy.html#wp1029629)

See the "**When to Use**" column for size of app and desired frequency of redeployment for each mode of deployment - to judge.

Comment: thanks very much..we decided to go with staging option as our app is not too big.